# How to persist Zustand with separated actions from state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, zustand

Based on this example: https://doichevkostia.dev/blog/authentication-store-with-zustand/

When I try to add `persist` middleware from `Zustand`, all the actions inside `actions` property on the store stops working and when I try to use them, throws an `setAccessToken is not a function`, in example.

Debugging I realized that the main issue is when I add `persist` middleware as I said.
I think the problem comes with the following declared type:

```js
/**
 * Required for zustand stores, as the lib doesn't expose this type
 */
export type ExtractState<S> = S extends {
    getState: () => infer T;
}
    ? T
    : never;

type Params<U> = Parameters<typeof useStore<typeof authStore, U>>;
```

but actually I do not know how to modify this type for working with `persist` middleware.

Am I wrong? I'm kind of lost at this point I don't know what I should do to get this example to work with `persist`. I've been looking the official docs but can't figure out what to do.